# How can I best fix and reinforce this door that has flat concealed hinges which are misaligned

Tags: cabinetry, hinges, door

The door hinges seem to be not lined up with the cupboard panel. We will eventually replace it all but for now I need a way to either fix or reinforce the door so it doesn’t keep coming off the cupboard
[image]

EDIT: I’ve got two options in mind. One is to try and fill everything with wood filler and then re-align the hinges again, which I’m not sure how strong it’ll be and the other is to use metal backplates to bolt the hinge attachments to the door but I feel this will still mean the door will still fall off over time but the hinges are may be more securely attached. Though I’m open to other options of course!

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Your question may be unclear.  Is the problem the tear out on the particle board panel or that this is not the original door panel and the hinge locations do not match?

Comment: The hinge locations match close enough for it to latch on but not quite perfectly which causes the door to collide when closing with the other door (double doors on this cupboard). This (I suspect) has then caused some strain on the hinges over time which then loosens them, making the door eventually fall off completely multiple times (and yes also the tear out)

Comment: It's very unclear what's going on here with half the hinges not in the images, but if your problem is primarily the stripped screw holes we have more than one prior Q&A that cover options for that. In this case I would strongly recommend filled epoxy since I've used it for screw-hole repairs on a hinge holding heavy cupboard doors (mostly glass) which have held up well since (3+ years). After filling and waiting for a full cure (at least a full day if not longer) you will need to re-drill pilot holes and *cautiously* reinsert the screws so as not to over-tighten and risk stripping the holes.

Answer (score 1):

Google “euro cup hinge screw insert“

Drill out the stripped screw holes and put in the inserts. Reattach your hinges. They have a number of adjustments in the x y and z axes, so you should be able to align them.

[image: plastic doohickeys]
Image source, [https://www.amazon.com/Hinge-Dowel-Screws-Pack-Hinges/dp/B005MXBPHM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005MXBPHM) —- absolutely not a recommendation.

Comment: These are unfortunately unsuitable, the bits where the door and cupboard attach by the hinge are parallel to each other when shut instead of 90degrees. It’s a really weird one

Comment: @UmayrDawood those inserts have nothing to do with the way the door closes - it's just a method of securing the hinge in damaged hole. It would work with _ANY_ hinge. But I agree with you in that it probably won't work - but not because of how the hinge works, but because of the amount of damage visible in your picture.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn’t see the inserts at all and thought you were talking about the hinge 